# How to pass byte array values from AngularJS to Asp.net WebAPI?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI and it is as under

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddLead")]
public void InsertLead(Document doc)
{
  leadRepository.InsertLead(doc);
}
```

The **Document class** is as under

```
public class Document
{
  public int DocumentId { get; set; }
  public byte[] DocumentData { get; set; }

}
```

Now we can make out that the property **DocumentData** is of Byte Array. A typical value will be

[image]

My client application is in AngularJS. How can I pass Byte Array to the DocumentData Field from AngularJS.?

Thanks

Comment: Is doing a base64 of the byte array an option? That way you could just post it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are still sending an object to ASP.NET like below. What you need to do is to fill property DocumentData with your byte[] data.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST', 
    data: {
       DocumentId: id,
       DocumentData: new Uint8Array()
    }

})
```